# Spring JPA not deleting entity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

When I try to delete a review, nothing is deleted and nothing is thrown.
I've already tried changing some of the cascade types but at the moment I can't figure out what the problem is. At first, I was using the delete method provided by 'CrudRepository', where you have to pass the object reference instead of deleting by Id, but it didn't work also.

#### Entities

```java
@Entity(name = "product_postgresql")
@Getter
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String sku;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String designation;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double aggregatedRating;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    protected Product() {
    }

    public Product(final String sku, final String designation, final String description, final double aggregatedRating) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.description = description;
        this.aggregatedRating = aggregatedRating;
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Entity(name = "review_postgresql")
public class Review {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Version
    private long version;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String approvalStatus;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "review", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Setter
    private List<Vote> votes;

    private String report;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate publishingDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String funFact;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double rating;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_sku", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    protected Review() {
    }

    public Review(final String id, final long version, final String approvalStatus, final String text,
                  final String report, final LocalDate publishingDate, final String funFact, final Double rating,
                  final Product product, final User user) {

        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;
        this.text = text;
        this.report = report;
        this.publishingDate = publishingDate;
        this.funFact = funFact;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.product = product;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "user_postgresql")
@Getter
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Email
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role; //why multiple roles?

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String nif;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vote> votes;

    protected User() {
    }

    public User(final String id, final String email, final String password, final String fullName,
                final String role, final String nif, final String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.role = role;
        this.nif = nif;
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity(name = "vote_postgresql")
@Getter
public class Vote implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VoteKey id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String vote;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("user_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("review_id")
    @JoinColumn(name = "review_id", nullable = false)
    private Review review;

    protected Vote() {
    }

    public Vote(User user, Review review, String vote) {
        this.id = new VoteKey(user.getId(), review.getId());
        this.user = user;
        this.review = review;
        this.vote = vote;
    }
}
```

#### JPA Repository

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(value="spring.repositories.targetPackage", havingValue = "postgresql")
public interface ReviewRepositoryPostgresql extends CrudRepository<Review, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM review_postgresql r WHERE r.id = :id")
    void deleteById(String id);
}
```

Comment: Is the delete query printed in the logs?

Comment: There won't be a delete query if you have the Product or User that reference it in the persistence unit. As Flydog answer hinted at, the relationships from Product->Review and User->Review are cascade all, which means that any Review found in those lists will be persisted to the database. So you cannot delete a review without first removing it from those collections as JPA will just find it there and re-persist it, canceling out the delete operation or (at times) being worse and issuing the delete and then re-inserting it.

Comment: You must maintain bidirectional relationships and ensure both sides are in synch with what you want in the database yourself. You might get by if the User and Product's 'review' lists aren't loaded, but safest strategy is always to maintain the collections yourself and remove their reference to the Review you want to delete before deleting it. JPA can have various levels of caching, so it'll save you problems down the line to just always keep objects in synch.

Comment: "DELETE FROM review_postgresql r WHERE r.id = :id" isn't going to work unless you don't have anything (votes) referencing that review. Cascade delete only work on objects - so votes will be left behind when using JPQL or SQL queries directly. If nothing is being done at all - you are likely not running this in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem might be caused by the bidirectional relationships between the entities, which require synchronization of both sides when performing operations.
2. To delete a Review entity, you need to remove it from the Product and User entities that reference it, otherwise the foreign key constraints will prevent the deletion.
3. You can use orphanRemoval = true in the @OneToMany annotations of Product and User entities to automatically delete the Review entity when it is removed from the collections.
4. Alternatively, you can use entityManager.remove (review) instead of tokenRepository.delete (review), which will cascade the removal operation to the associated entities.